# Drawing a circle including all given co-ordinates in Bing Maps API

Tags: javascript, html, api, dictionary, bing

I have a set of coordinates in the form

```
const locations = [{
               lat: 46.233226,
               lng: 6.055737
           }, {
               lat: 46.2278,
               lng: 6.0510
           }, {
               lat: 46.23336,
               lng: 6.0471
           }];
```

This is the code I use to plot the coordinates.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>addmultiplelayeritemsHTML</title>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
    <style type='text/css'>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            font-family: 'Segoe UI', Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id='myMap' style='width: 100%; height: 100%;'></div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function loadMapScenario() {
            var apiKey = "API KEY";
            var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {
                credentials: apiKey
            });
            const locations = [{
                lat: 46.233226,
                lng: 6.055737
            }, {
                lat: 46.2278,
                lng: 6.0510
            }, {
                lat: 46.23336,
                lng: 6.0471
            }];
            locations.forEach((location) => {
                let marker = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(location.lat, location.lng));
                map.entities.push(marker);
            });

        }
    </script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?key=YourBingMapsKey&callback=loadMapScenario' async defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to draw a circle including all those points in the Bing Map API. I want to do it in HTML.

Also, I want to generate a polygon connecting these points. I want both as different HTML pages. Any help is highly appreciated.